# How to get header info from web directory in java

Tags: java, http

I want to extract the header information from web pages using plain Java. For example if the page is `www.stackoverflow.com` and the path is `/questions` the program should return http header info from `www.stackoverflow.com/questions`. So far I have this method:

```
private static String queryWeb(String page, String path) throws IOException {
        InetAddress requestedWebIP = InetAddress.getByName(page);
        if ((path == null) || (path.equals ("")) {
            path = "/";
        }
        try (
                Socket toWebSocket = new Socket(requestedWebIP, 80);
                BufferedOutputStream outPutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(toWebSocket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(toWebSocket.getInputStream()))
        ) {
            String request = "HEAD " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
            outPutStream.write(request.getBytes());
            outPutStream.flush();
            String input;
            String result = "";

            while (!(input = inputStream.readLine()).equals("")) {
                System.out.println(input);
                result = result + input + "\n";
            }

            return result;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred during IO");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This works fine for pages with no additional path, i.e `www.stackoverflow.com`. However whenever I try anything along the lines of `www.stackoverflow.com/questions` I get a `nullpointerException` in the while loop. Poking around with a debugger suggests that the inputStream is null, but again only when the path is specified. So this works:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

But this doesn't(?):

```
HEAD /questions HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

So I assume that the inpustream is empty because the HEAD command fails, but why does it not accept this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `Host` header:

> A Host header field must be sent in all HTTP/1.1 request messages.

I've amended your code to send `Host`:

```
private static String queryWeb(String host, String path) throws IOException {
    InetAddress requestedWebIP = InetAddress.getByName(host);
    if ((path == null) || (path.equals(""))) {
        path = "/";
    }
    try (
            Socket toWebSocket = new Socket(requestedWebIP, 80);
            BufferedOutputStream outPutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(toWebSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(toWebSocket.getInputStream()))
    ) {
        String request = "HEAD " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                "Host: " + host + "\r\n\r\n";
        outPutStream.write(request.getBytes());
        outPutStream.flush();
        String input;
        String result = "";

        while (!(input = inputStream.readLine()).equals("")) {
            System.out.println(input);
            result = result + input + "\n";
        }

        return result;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred during IO");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The following code

```
queryWeb("example.com", "/");
```

returns `200 OK`, while

```
queryWeb("example.com", "/questions");
```

returns `404 Not Found` (as expected).

`www.stackoverflow.com` works too (it returns a redirect to `https` version).

Nothing fails with scary exceptions.

Please also note that

1. Path has to be %-escaped (I've omitted this)
2. Usually, it is much easier (and safer) to use some library like Apache HttpComponents HttpClient, google-http-client, etc. Even the standard `URL().openConnection()` allows to avoid a lot of dirty work and mistakes.